# Connection issues with fuse esb when connecting to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, c3p0, postgresql-12, fuseesb, jdbc-postgres

I am trying to connect fuse esb with postgresql database. Postgresql database is the latest version (12.6) and the driver provided by fuse is "postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar" (osgi) under jdk 1.7. Bellow issues are seen.

1. when checking the connection count from pgadmin after esb starting, it shows that connection count for the respective db user grows rapidly and then decreases to 0. This repeats until I shutdow the ESB
2. "exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed." error is printed in esb logs continuously until I stop esb.
3. "com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@33218ca2 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed." error is printed in esb logs continuously
4. "com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source".error is printed in esb logs continuously

Any clues for above issues are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

All issues were resolved after upgrading to latest postgresql driver